# Wrong size of superscripts in other fontsizes than \normalsize

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, superscripts

please look at the following example:

When I change the fontsize to `\Huge` the superscript ist too big in relation to the x.

But when I set the same fontsize as `\Huge` by the `\fontsize` command, this Problem does not appear.

What is happening here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

Compare the size of the superscripts with the $x$.

\string\normalsize~(OK):
\[ x³ \]

\string\Huge~(The superscript is too big. Why?):
\Huge
\[ x³ \]

\normalsize
The same fontsize as \string\Huge, but selected by the \string\fontsize~command (OK):
\fontsize{25}{30}\selectfont
\[ x³ \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\Huge` then the math text and script fonts are

```
> \TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(0)/m/n/24.88 .
l.17 \showthe\textfont0

? 
> \TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(0)/m/n/20.74 .
l.18 \showthe\scriptfont0
```

If you use `\fontsize{25}{30}\selectfont` then the fonts are

```
> \TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(0)/m/n/25 .
l.24 \showthe\textfont0

? 
> \TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(0)/m/n/17.49992 .
l.25 \showthe\scriptfont0
```

The second set is using `unicode-math` default of setting the script font to 0.7 the text font size.

`\Huge` is 24.88pt rather than 25pt and the latex format sets

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

so script size for `\@xxvpt` (24.88pt) is `\@xxpt` which is 20.74pt.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about `\DeclareMathSizes`. Now I understand.

Comment: @user125730 of course the math sizes are tuned for cm fonts where the 24pt is not simply the scaled version of the 10pt one and are probably completely inappropriate here but history is what history is:-)